# can't install gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'

Tags: ruby, rubygems, twitter-bootstrap

When trying to bundle install get error. I get the same error with empty project.

```
 Installing libv8 (3.3.10.4) with native extensions
   Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
    *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
   necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
       details.  You may need configuration options.

  Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby
    Checking for Python...Unable to build libv8: Python not found!


    Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.3
 .10.4 for inspection.
   Results logged to C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.3.10.4/ext/libv8/g
  em_make.out
   An error occured while installing libv8 (3.3.10.4), and Bundler cannot continue.

    Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.3.10.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Here is my Gemfile:
       source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
  gem 'rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.0'
  # Bundle edge Rails instead:
  # gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
   gem'devise'

  gem 'mysql2'

group :deployment do
 gem 'pg'
end
```

gem 'activemerchant'

```
Gems used only for assets and not required
```

in production environments by default.
   group :assets do
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
    gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
   gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

```
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
```

# gem 'therubyracer'

```
 gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

  gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Comment: It's hopeless at the moment because v8 won't build on windows. Also of these gems you probably want one or the other: bootstrap-sass, twitter-bootstrap-rails

Answer (score 1):

libv8 requires Python to be installed and added to the Windows path.

- Steps

  - Download and install [Python27](http://www.python.org/getit/releases/2.7/)
  - Right click on Computer -> Properties -> Advanced Settings -> Environment Variables
  - Under "System variables" find Path and choose edit
  - Add "c:\Python26;"

Note: I had to restart Aptana in order for it to recognize the new Python path.